# Should I put a game on an SSD or HDD for best performance?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I have two disks:

- System disk: Corsair SSD Force GT 120 GB
- Storage disk: 1 TB Samsung Spinpoint F3 HD103SJ

Where should I put a game for best performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most games depend mostly on loading in data from your storage.

So, in order to optimize the delay of level or scene loading, you should put your games on a SSD.

Please note that games that involve a lot of writes, like a Minecraft world, better fit a HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the game.  RTS games, FPS games, Strategy games touch the hard drive to load maps.  In those games, you'll only notice a performance difference at the start of a map.  You'll see a negligible difference in fps and/or performance during the map.

Now if you are in a game that loads a lot of maps or has a lot of map transitions, like the Total War series, then an SSD will make a good difference.